# Avoid unnecessary @Component construction during spring unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

Assume two `@Component`'s are defined, like this:

```
@Component
public class UnderTesting {
}
```

```
@Component
public class Irrelevant {
}
```

The unit test is like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
public Test_UnderTesting {
    @Autowired
    private UnderTesting foo;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
    }
}
```

When running this test case with `mvn test`, spring will construct component `Irrelevant` even though it's completely irrelevant.

In my case the component `Irrelevant` **cannot** be constructed due to unavailability of complex dependencies in the unit test environment.

My question is: how to avoid constructing `Irrelevant` (and other unnecessary components) during unit test ?

I'm kind new to spring boot, so I may have been heading a wrong direction, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to understand is, as soon as you use `@SpringBootTest`, it's not a unit test anymore. The point of using that annotation is, that your application context starts as similar as possible to the production use.

You could define a separate configuration class for this test case specifically, where you only create a bean of the class UnderTesting, like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestConfiguration.class})
```

where in TestConfiguration.class you could create a bean factory method like this:

```
public UnderTesting underTesting() {
    return new UnderTesting();
}
```

but i would rather look if you can write this test as a real unit test (if that's what you want), without using any Spring Boot functionality, and mock any dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a `test` profile to use when you run your tests and annotate your `Irrelevant` class with `@Profile("!test")`?

Comment: This not gonna work, since `Irrelevant` has its own test cases.

Comment: Then the only option is I think passing a custom configuration to your test as @dunni wrote

Answer (score 0):

#### The simplest way using mockito:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public Test_UnderTesting {

    @MockBean
    private Irrelevant irrelevant; //Autowiring the unnecessary component as a mock

    @Autowired
    private UnderTesting foo;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
    }
}
```

#### Dependencies required:

- [Spring Boot Starter Test](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test)
- [Mockito Core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core)

Answer (score -1):

We can load the component lazily, i.e. by using @Lazy annotation on top of @Component

Please refer this link for more information:  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation